# Azure B2C Client Login and API Call - Azure Function

Tags: azure-active-directory, msal.js

I've got a .NET Core application authenticating via Azure B2C however I now want to authenticate the REST API calls in Javascript using the bearer token.

The REST APIs (Azure Function) exist at a different URI to the Web Application hence another Azure Application has been created to support and linked to the existing Web Application as per the Microsoft KB's

Obviously the Javascript REST API needs to pass the authorization header along with the bearer token.

I'm trying to plumb the MSAL JS library using Msal.UserAgentApplication and call the acquireTokenSilent.

Is this the correct approach?  Or should the Web App share the token from ASP.NET into JS by some means.

Comment: So you have something like Browser--> JS API (backend for frontend) ->  API (.NET)?

Comment: More like Browser -> API.NET (Backend Web) and Browser -> API Azure Function that serves the client frontend components (JS)

Comment: Then I would recommend PKCE flow, check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa#overview-of-authentication-options

You could do it with the implicit flow but it is not as secure. Essentially your browser does the login (redirects to b2c), gets an access token and calls any APIs.

MSAL should support both flows.

Comment: I think it's ok to generate access token by msal.js in your spa and call api via it.

Comment: yeah I've noticed its painful at the moment, obviously since my app isnt SPA. Basically its authenticating twice, once via the ASP.NET Core MVC framework (serverside) and then via the MSAL JS. It doesnt prompt the user to reenter the password/username but it still displays the login popup for the moment.